# Prestashop - make shortcode from view

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I made a plugin that renders code and hooks it inside product page. I want to make it more flexible and hook that view in specific places in product description.

Is there a way to make it as shortcode, so I could put [blablabla] in product description and render it in a specific view? (`do_shortcode()` equivalent in Wordpress)

So far, I render that by hooking it in the end of product description.

```
public function hookDisplayProductTab() {
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'maps.tpl');
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how make it work in an MVC environment. I just simply use the hooks in Prestashop to render code. I've no idea from where to start and what type of concept could be used.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how make it work in mvc environment. I just simply use the hooks in prestashop to render code. I've no idea from where to start and what type of concept could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to change position of every module html that calls `displayProductTab` hook, then look for `{$HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB}` inside `product.tpl` and put it in desired position.

If you wish to change the order of modules rendering `displayProductTab` then go to backoffice menu `Modules -> Positions` and search for `productTab` position. You will see modules that are hooked to this position and you can change the display order of them.

If you wish to call your module's hook in a specific place you can call your hook inside templates like this.

```
{hook h='displayProductTab' mod='yourmodulename'}
```

This executes `hookDisplayProductTab()` of your module inside templates. If for example you want to execute hook of every module, you remove the `mod='yourmodulename'` part.

```
{hook h='displayProductTab}
```

If you wish to have certain parameters available inside hook, you can specify them.

```
{hook h='displayProductTab' mod='mymodulename' cur_page=$page_name}
```

And you can access the parameter in your hook.

```
public function hookDisplayProductTab($params)
{
    $myParam = $params['cur_page'];
}
```

Comment: Great, gonna start from that. Unfortunately I can't vote it useful ;)

Comment: But you can mark it as answered if it worked for you.